# Laravel elixir version error

Tags: gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

The gulp watch is crashing every time when I save to fast(gulp make the tasks a bit slowly because my pc is not that good) I get this error:

```
[00:26:09] Finished 'version' after 151 ms
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'projectpath\build\js\core-527103978a.js'
    at Error (native)
```

and then crashes.

What can I do to rerun gulp watch without going to console and start it,or how I can fix this?